# How do I search JSON API output for certain data

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am very new to JSON and JavaScript and want to browse the JSON output from the OpenWeatherMap API for certain data.

Does somebody know how I can do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look at other questions. Then read the help section on how to ask a question. This question is way too broad as it stands, there are no examples of the JSON or of what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample API Weather from d.weather**

```
 api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecase?lat=50.8609&lon=-0.08014&&units=metric
```

**HTML page for pulling the openweather JSON data**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Weather</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.7.0/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

<script>
function getWeather(callback) {
    var weather = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=51.5072&lon=0.1275&units=metric';
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: weather,
      success: callback
    });
}

// get data:
getWeather(function (data) {
    console.log('weather data received');
    console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].description); 
    console.log(data.list[0].weather[0].main);  
});

getWeather(function (data) {
    document.write('weather data received');
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].weather[0].description);
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].weather[0].main);
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].main.temp);
    document.write('<br>');
    document.write(data.list[0].main[0].dt_txt);
    document.write('<br>');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Html page for pulling the JSON data**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Javascript -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUrl(newLocation){
    window.location = newLocation;
    return false;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#btn382").click(function(){       
        /* set no cache */
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $.getJSON("weather.json", function(data){
            var html = [];

            /* loop through array */
            $.each(data, function(index, d){           
                html.push("Team : ", d.Teams, ", ",
                          "Long : ", d.Long, ", ",
                          "Lat : ", d.Lat, ", ",
              "Weather : ", d.Weather, "<br>");        
            });


            $("#div381").html(html.join('')).css("background-color", "orange");
        }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */
            /* alert(jqXHR.responseText) */
            alert("error occurred!");
        });
    });
});
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<a name="#ajax-getjson-example"></a>
<div id="example-section38">   
    <div>Football weather</div>
    <div id="div381"></div>
    <button id="btn382" type="button">Team location</button>
</div>
```

**weather.json**

```
{
    "Teams":"Wycombe Wanderers",
    "Long":-0.800299,
    "Lat":51.6306,
    "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.6306&lon=-0.800299&mode=html"
  },
  {
    "Teams":"Livingston",
    "Long":-3.52207,
    "Lat":55.8864,
    "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.8864&lon=-3.52207&mode=html"
  },
  {
    "Teams":"Brighton and Hove Albion",
    "Long":-0.08014,
    "Lat":50.8609,
    "Weather":"  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50.8609&lon=-0.08014&mode=html"
  },
```